# How to trigger hover event on child's object via its parent?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I have written a custom react component which has an animation on :hover. This component is a **child** of a different **parent** component. What I would like to do is to trigger **child's** :hover when hovering over parent's component. Is it possible to simulate it via css (if it isn't then how can it be achieved)?

**Test Case:** I have a blog post card that when hovering on lightens up. Within it, in form of a child element I have a Link/a component which has its own css/:hover animation and also upon clicking redirects to a given href page. The effect that I would like to achieve is to animate both elements (and not only parent element) when hovering on parent as well as triggering child's click event when clicking on the parent.

Answer (score 0):

If you can share the code would be easier to explain but what you can do is in your parent component main wrapper/div you can set `onMouseEnter` event and inside this event you can set a boolean state. Then in your main wrapper/div in childs component you can get className as props and you can set conditional classNames controlled by this state (true or false) and do necessary modifications in your css.

An example for conditional className

```
className={`${isOnHover ? "hoverClass" : "noHoverClass"}`}
```

Comment: I've tried to explain it in more details in the "Test Case" section

Comment: I have created simulation have a look in here, I hope that helps now https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-v3mhdt?file=src/App.js

Comment: That's useful thanks, but still the clicking event is an issue (how to pass it down the hierarchy?). Also when a child element will be on its own (not attached to this specific parent component) it will not be able to behave as it suppose to (on hover will not animate it)

Comment: You can use same logic in child element and you can set 3rd 4th classNames in correct order. In the end component will take the className that supposed to be active `${isChildHover ? "hoverChildClass" : " "}` like this.